# Hide Rows VBA Code of Cells Not Containing Words From Array Mismatch

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, show-hide, autofilter

Basically I have a vba code that runs really well. But when I try to duplicate it to another command button just changing the sheet name and the sub name, it doesn't work and it says Type Mismatch. This is the VBA code that runs properly.

```
    Sub hide_Rows_by_cell_value()
    Dim wb As Workbook, CompInfo As Worksheet, MufgClient As Worksheet
    Dim srcCl As Range, lr As Long, FltCol As Range, cl As Range, hideRng As Range
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set CompInfo = wb.Sheets("Company Information")
    Set MufgClient = wb.Sheets("MUFG Client")
    
    Set srcCl = CompInfo.Cells(18, 9)
    arr = Split(srcCl.Value, ",")
    
    lr = MufgClient.Range("AC" & MufgClient.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set FltCol = MufgClient.Range("AC3:AC" & lr) '2nd Row contains table headers
    
    For Each cl In FltCol
        chk = 0
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        chk = chk + InStr(1, cl.Value, Trim(arr(i)), vbTextCompare)
        Next
        If chk = 0 Then
            If hideRng Is Nothing Then
            Set hideRng = cl
            Else
            Set hideRng = Union(hideRng, cl)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    hideRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
    End Sub
```

And this is the VBA code that says type mismatch

```
  Sub hide_rows_by_cell_value2()
  Dim wb As Workbook, MUFGInfo As Worksheet, LendingFunding As Worksheet
  Dim srcCl As Range, lr As Long, FltCol As Range, cl As Range, hideRng As Range
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set MUFGInfo = wb.Sheets("MUFG Information")
  Set LendingFunding = wb.Sheets("Lending & Funding")

  Set srcCl = MUFGInfo.Cells(18, 9)
  arr = Split(srcCl.Value, ",")

  lr = LendingFunding.Range("AC" & LendingFunding.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set FltCol = LendingFunding.Range("AC3:AC" & lr) '2nd Row Contains table headers

  For Each cl In FltCol
    chk = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    chk = chk + InStr(1, cl.Value, Trim(arr(i)), vbTextCompare)
    Next
    If chk = 0 Then
        If hideRng Is Nothing Then
        Set hideRng = cl
        Else
        Set hideRng = Union(hideRng, cl)
        End If
    End If

  Next

  hideRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True

  End Sub
```

The mismatch is in

```
chk = chk + InStr(1, cl.Value, Trim(arr(i)), vbTextCompare)
```

I already checked the cell and it is still correct 18,9 (row 18 column i). I also make the range same with the first vba code since the sheet content is a copy paste from the previous sheet

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `cl.Value` and `arr(i)` when you get the issue?

Comment: @jamheadart could you give me the example of cl.Value and arr(i) value? Because I don't understand what you mean. If you ask me the content of the cell (18,9), the example is Logistics, E-Commerce, Food & Beverage, Wholesales Trading (The content of cell I18)

Comment: @jamheadart you mean this? cl.Value = Error 2042 and arr(i) = "Logistics"

Comment: Yes exactly, so your issue is `cl.Value` - that is the root of the mismatch error! It can't compare an error with the string value "Logistics" so you need to find out where in the range `LendingFunding.Range("AC3:AC" & lr)` you have an error instead of an actual value.

Comment: Because of `LendingFunding.Range("AC3:AC" & lr)` your code is cycling through the range "AC3" to the last row of "AC" - somewhere in there is an error instead of a value.

Comment: @jamheadart I already knew the answer. It's because Error 2042 in google says related to #N/A. My data in Lending & Funding sheet still contains #N/A a few. I replace all #N/A(s) with 0 and it works. Thank you so much Jam, cannot do this without you either :)

Comment: Good work! I posted an answer which means you could ignore errors in the column, but I imagine it's a lot easier to actually get rid of those errors. Have fun!

Comment: @jamheadart Well, I'm nothing without you all. I'm just a kid who got a project in a company using Macro Excel :D Thank you very much once again.

Comment: I got started with a few macros in Excel, learned so much from StackOverflow, and now I'm a full-time software developer.

Comment: @jamheadart Wow, it's really Cool Sick! Well, I'm gonna learn more and more bout this. Yes, StackOverflow really helps me with VBA(s). I hope a lot of users are still active in this website. Kinda my place to go to for Macro assistance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems you have an error in the range that you're checking (Column "AC")

You could gloss over errors in your check cycle by adding an error check wrapped around the code within the loop:

```
  For Each cl In FltCol
    If Not IsError(cl) Then
      chk = 0
      For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        chk = chk + InStr(1, cl.Value, Trim(arr(i)), vbTextCompare)
      Next
      If chk = 0 Then
        If hideRng Is Nothing Then
          Set hideRng = cl
        Else
          Set hideRng = Union(hideRng, cl)
        End If
      End If
    End If

  Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The code above is working if the data in your sheet does not contain #N/A because the error is in cl.Value which is Error = 2042. Replace all #N/A(s) with 0 only.